# can't change font size in listview xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Why can't change font size in listview

i want increase and decrease font size in all cells in listview
but i can't make that by normal code

```
txt.Fontsize = 20;
```

this my code in xaml

```
 <ListView  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.865" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="listview" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding names}" ><ListView.ItemTemplate>

       <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>

                    <StackLayout  Padding="10"  VerticalOptions="Center" >
        <Label  x:Name="txt" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding _index}  "></Label> 

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: This is because you're in a ```DataTemplate```  and a ```DataTemplate``` is treated as it's own view.  The name "txt" shouldn't show in the code behind and a DataTemplate doesn't have code behind.  You can make a custom control and use that in the DataTemplate and perform a binding but you still can't use it in code behind the same way.  There is a way to travel the LogicTree and get it done but that's not the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

i found solution by slider value

```
<Slider Maximum="50" Minimum="20"  x:Name="slider" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.1,0.6,0.02" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" ></Slider>
```

and in lable :-

```
    <Label  x:Name="txt" FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},Path=Value}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding _text}"></Label>
```